# React-Native importing Realm causes error

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to develop an app with react-native and realm. But as soon as I try to import Realm in any component I get the following two errors:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:61Cannot read property 'debugHosts' of undefined
    handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:61
    handleError @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:115
    reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:30
    guardedLoadModule @ require.js:60
    _require @ require.js:49
    (anonymous function) @ require-0.js:1
    executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:18
    onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:33

ExceptionsManager.js:61Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
    handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:61
    handleError @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:115
    reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:30
    guard @ MessageQueue.js:43
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:94
    onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:39
```

Everything works fine, until I try to import Realm (`import Realm from 'realm';`).

- I added it in the `package.json`.
- Installed it with `npm install` and linked it with `rnpm link realm`.
- I restarted the packager and still it does not work.
- I tried to import it with `var Realm = require('realm')`. Same error

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "15.2.1",
    "react-native": "0.31.0",
    "react-native-action-button": "^1.1.11",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.35.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "realm": "^0.14.3",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
},
```

I am using VS Code with the React Native Tools and Genymotion.

Comment: Did you tried running clean and then build from xcode?

Comment: cleaned the package cache with `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh clean`. Did not help.